# !ClrStack shows the Unmanaged Call stack

Tags: c#, c++

I have created console Application from which I have called the Win32 Project where it throws an access violation exception. I have attached My custom filter in `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`. When I use `!clrstack` command, it shows the unmanaged call stack but MSDN says Clrstack will provide a stack trace of managed code only.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx

Please help .

Program.cs

```
public void ExceptionMethod()
    {

         ExceptionCreator.CreateAccessViolationException();

    }
```

**Win32 Project:**

ErrorReportWritter.h

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DbgHelp.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace System::Text;

public ref class ErrorReportWritter
{
public:
    static void InstallHandler();
};
```

ErrorReportWritter.cpp

```
LONG WINAPI MyExceptionFilter(__in struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo) 
{
    //For test purpose, Dump location will be the solution location itself
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA("Test.dmp", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,

        0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if ((hFile != NULL) && (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE))
    {
        // Create the maxidump 
        MINIDUMP_TYPE mdt = (MINIDUMP_TYPE)(MiniDumpWithFullMemory |
            MiniDumpWithFullMemoryInfo |
            MiniDumpWithHandleData |
            MiniDumpWithThreadInfo |
            MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules);

        //MINIDUMP_TYPE mdt = MiniDumpNormal;

        MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION mei;
        mei.ThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
        mei.ClientPointers = FALSE;
        mei.ExceptionPointers = ExceptionInfo;


        BOOL rv = MiniDumpWriteDump(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentProcessId(), hFile, mdt, &mei, 0, 0);

        //TODO: put a check for failure return value and throw exception in that case

        // Close the file 
        CloseHandle(hFile);

    }

    //TODO: Still need to decide if the search next functionality is needed for final solution
    if (oldFilter == NULL)
    {
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
    }

    LONG ret = oldFilter(ExceptionInfo);

    return ret;
}

void ErrorReportWritter::InstallHandler()
{
    //Returns the address of the previous exception filter established with the function.
    //A NULL return value means that there is no current top-level exception handler.
    oldFilter = SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(MyExceptionFilter);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Screenshot of Call stack is attached in this link http://i.stack.imgur.com/ghUYs.png

Comment: Where exactly is your unmanaged crash? Your Cpp project is managed code, too.

Comment: ExceptionCreator.cpp
#include "ExceptionCreator.h"

#pragma comment ( lib, "dbghelp.lib" )


using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace System::Text;


void ExceptionCreator::CreateAccessViolationException()
{
 Marshal::StructureToPtr(42, IntPtr(42), true);
}

Comment: That is *managed* code. Look at the namespaces you are using. That means you created a managed cpp project. Maybe you meant to create an *unmanaged* (some would say *normal*) Win32 application?

Comment: how to create project which is unmanaged ?

Comment: yes.I want to create project which is Unmanaged

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is *managed* C++. (or C++/CLI or whatever your Visual Studio version supports).

To create an *unmanaged* Win32 project, for example in Visual Studio 2015, got to `File` -> `New Project` and then select `Templates` -> `Visual C++` -> `Win32 Project`.